Merging the two "replace" methods?
Is it possible to merge the two "replace" methods in the example below into one? The intention is for scalability.
import pandas as pd

custom_groups = {"odd": [1, 3, 5], "even": [2, 4]}

s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

s.replace(custom_groups["odd"], "odd").replace(custom_groups["even"], "even")


Not really sure what your use case is, but why wouldn't you just rebuild custom_groups into a mappable form? s.map({1: 'odd', 2: 'even', 3: 'odd', 4: 'even', 5: 'odd'})

Hi Henry. Do you happen to know if there is anything like s.replace({[1, 3, 5]: "odd", [2, 4]: "even"}) to skip the step of creating a table of one-to-one relationships?

There is not a way to do that because that doesn't make sense because lists can't be dictionary keys. You can't directly compare the values in your Series to a list without testing membership. Any way you look at replacement you eventually need a 1-to-1 mapping. Even if you're doing value in N comparisons to make it appear like an N-to-1 mapping.

When you pass a list to replace that function still has to test against individual values eventually. Technically, it builds a temp list containing the replace value of the same length as your Series then masking out based on the to_replace list then fills from the temp list (at least in the current version of Pandas 2.2.2). In this case for the first replace that'd be a temp list of ["odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd"] then create a masking array [True, False, True, False, True] then fill True values in masking array from the odd list.

A dict-like mapper on the other hand is highly efficient in its replacement, though map can require backfilling any unaccounted for values. Which is again why I asked what your actual use case is, because in this example inversing your custom_groups and passing it to map would likely be both quicker and less space intensive than either chaining replaces or building out a separate Series object.

Thank you Henry for confirming that supplying one-to-one relationships is necessary when substituting values. I need a bit of time to work out how to write the code but I understand the flow now.

Most pythonic/efficient approach: reverse the dictionary with a dictionary comprehension and replace once:
d = {v:k for k, l in custom_groups.items()
     for v in l}
s.replace(d)

Output:
0     odd
1    even
2     odd
3    even
4     odd
dtype: object

Intermediate d:
{1: 'odd', 3: 'odd', 5: 'odd', 2: 'even', 4: 'even'}

timings
This is ~2x faster than using a Series+explode on small datasets, and tends to the same speed for large datasets.
## OP's example
# dictionary comprehension
745 µs ± 31.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# Series explode
1.58 ms ± 213 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

## 1000 keys dictionary / 10 items per list / 10_000 items Series
# dictionary comprehension
163 ms ± 6.61 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Series explode
203 ms ± 64.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

generalization
If you have to do this often with different dictionaries, you can even use a function to invert the dictionary
def invert(d):
    return {v:k for k, l in custom_groups.items()
            for v in (l if isinstance(l, list) else [l])}
s.replace(invert(custom_groups))


Thank you mozway for the detailed explanation. dict_comprehension indeed screams pythonic. With you and Henry in agreement, I believe this must be the "obvious way to do it".

Code
tmp = pd.Series(custom_groups).explode()
out = s.replace(pd.Series(tmp.index, index=tmp.values))

out:
0     odd
1    even
2     odd
3    even
4     odd
dtype: object


Thanks, Panda. I have a feeling this might be the best solution. I will just give it a bit more time to see if there are any other syntax ideas before marking yours as the answer.

You could write a loop:
for key in custom_groups:
    s.replace(custom_groups[key], key)


Thanks, John. That is clever! However, I am keen to know if there is a way to do it without a loop. I understand the "to_replace" parameter can take a dictionary, allowing replacing multiple single values with corresponding single values at once e.g. s.replace({1: "odd", 2: "even"}). I hope to replace multiple lists of single values with corresponding single values in one go e.g. something like s.replace({[1, 3, 5]: "odd", [2, 4]: "even"}).
